# Kendo AutoComplete Empty Filter in Querystring - serverfiltering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use serverfiltering for autocomplete in Kendo UI (ASP.NET 5, MVC6)
Due to fact that Autocomplete isn't available in MVC Wrapper, i had to use the code below:

```
<script>
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverOperation: true,
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Content("~/api/Get")",
                type: "GET"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        }
    })

    $("#@Model.Name").kendoAutoComplete({
        placeholder: "@Model.Watermark",
        minLength: 3,
        filter: "contains",
        dataSource: dataSource

    });
</script>
```

The problem is that querystring send to controller looks like this :
?sort=&group=&filter=

So it doesn't include any filter information

On serverside im trying to map it to DataSourceRequest

Comment: Kendo autocomplete is available in an MVC wrapper... `@Html.Kendo.AutoCompleteFor()` http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete/index

Comment: It's not available for MVC 6. There are still some components missing in Wrapper for MVC6

Comment: Ah ok! Sorry, was not aware of this. Can you please post your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Right now im using following workaround to pass additional parameter to do serversidefiltering but still i'd like to use kendo native filtering for this:

```
<script>
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverOperation: true,
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Content("~/api/Get")",
                type: "GET",
                data: onAdditionalData
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        }
    })


    $("#@Model.Name").kendoAutoComplete({
        placeholder: "@Model.Watermark",
        minLength: 3,
        filter: "contains",
        dataSource: dataSource

    });

    function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#@Model.Name").val()
        };
    }
 </script>
```

Controller code:

```
    [Route("api/Get")]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string text = "")
    {
        var list = (new List<string>() { "value1", "value2", "value3", "test" } ).AsQueryable();
        return Json(list.Where(x => x.Contains(text)).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```